# Ruby on Rails: read user submited .txt file into variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm building a ruby on rails app that lets the user pick a file from their hard drive, and then writes specific lines from the text file into a database. I've built the form, but now I don't know how to get the content of the file into a variable, format it and then write it into the database.

I have a database table named drafts with colums set_1, set_2, set_3. I want to write line 13(from the text file) into set_1, line 165 into set_2 and line 317 into set_3. I also want to format the lines before writing them. In the file they look like this `------ FRF ------` and I only want `FRF`.

I've spent a lot of time searching stackoverflow and rubyonrails guides but have a hard time figuring this out. I'm very new to ruby and rails in general, so any help is appreciated.

Here's my controller (drafts_controller.rb):

```
class DraftsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @page_title = "Upload MTGO Draft"

        @draft = Draft.new
    end

    def create
        @draft = Draft.new(draft_params)
        if @draft.save
            flash[:notice] = "Draft Saved!"
            redirect_to drafts_show_path
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def index
        @page_title = "MTGO Draft"
    end

    def show
        @page_title = "MTGO Draft Replayer"
    end 

    def search
        @page_title = "Search MTGO Draft"
    end

    def destroy

    end

    def draft_params
        params.require(:draft).permit(:name, :set_1, :set_2, :set3, :file_setter)
    end
end
```

and my view: (new.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for @draft, :multipart => true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        Draft Log: <%= f.file_field :file_setter %>
        <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

here's the model (draft.rb)

```
class Draft < ActiveRecord::Base
    def file_setter=(file)
        path = file.tempfile.to_path.to_s
        lines = File.read(path).split("\r\n")
        self.set_1 = lines[12]
        self.set_2 = lines[164]
        self.set_3 = lines[316]
    end
    attr_accessor :file_setter
end
```

If you need more info or want to get into the whole app more he's a [gitHub repository](https://github.com/Shooshte/topdeckandwreck).

Thanks for the help.

Here's the log excerp:

```
Started POST "/drafts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-10 10:52:57 +0200
Processing by DraftsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8IjtOXuXm3fswWTslDTq5ijjo0dpCWHlu9X7UFb5prvawrZfkLC46v7PbqTgrSrvukLxAAoBIBftsGqiXv79JA==", "draft"=>{"file_setter"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005ee4a08 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150410-3067-1fssm13>, @original_filename="1", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"draft[file_setter]\"; filename=\"1\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.8ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `drafts` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-04-10 08:52:57', '2015-04-10 08:52:57')
  [1m[36m (41.6ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/drafts/show
Completed 302 Found in 57ms (ActiveRecord: 43.6ms)
```

Comment: Is your main problem is to read content from the text file?

Comment: My main problem is reading content and storing it in a variable (preferably array with an element for each line), so I can format it, and then write it into the database. Formatting and writing comes second, for now I just want to be open the file.

Comment: Is `path = file.tempfile.to_path.to_s` giving you proper path?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to check that. What I want to be able to do, is for the user to input a file from his hard-disk, so this should be generic?

Comment: You can get the text content from the file using `file.tempfile.read`. After that you can split things by `'\t\n'`

Comment: so I've set the file_setter path to 'path = file.tempfile.read' and it still won't write the values into the database. To be honest I have a hard time following, as I am new to ruby and to ruby on rails. Maybe if you can provide a more detailed description, or just dumb it down a bit? Thanks

Comment: done, also updated git repository

Comment: Update this line: ` lines = File.read(path).split("\r\n")` with ` lines = path.split("\r\n")`

Comment: still just writes null into database. Maybe you could write it up as an answes, the comment section is getting long

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your model:

```
def file_setter=(file)
  path = file.tempfile.to_path.to_s
  lines = File.read(path).split("\r\n")
  self.set_1 = lines[12]
  self.set_2 = lines[164]
  self.set_3 = lines[316]
end
```

In your form change the `file_field` value from `:file` to `:file_setter` like this:

```
<%= form_for @draft, :multipart => true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        Draft Log: <%= f.file_field :file_setter %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

// Its very important that you add `:multipart => true` to the `form_for` method. Otherwise file uploads wont work.

// Also add this to your model:

```
attr_accessor :file_setter
```

// In your controller you have to change this:

```
def draft_params
  params.require(:draft).permit(:name, :set_1, :set_2, :set3)
end
```

To this:

```
def draft_params
  params.require(:draft).permit(:name, :set_1, :set_2, :set3, :file_setter)
end
```

Comment: Also make sure you allow setting `file_setter` in your controller!!! If you dont add it to strong params the method wont even be called

Comment: Please post the call your generating from your logfile. I need to see the params hash

Comment: I'm sry, this opened fine on linux, then I opened it in notepad in windows and figured out formatting is gone, will repair soon

Comment: Its okay its just a problem with the notepad it only interprets \r\n as as line break and not just \n like the vi(m),  emacs, joe,... do I can read it.

Comment: Also it looks fine the `file_getter` is transmitted as a file upload not as text as I expected it. Please post the code of your model here (dont upload it, edit it to yout post) and als post the code of your view.

Comment: updated main post with model. Also deleted some old, irrelevant comments. The code to the relevant view was allready posted.

Comment: are you sure the file_setter method should be in my model? It still only writes created_at, updated_at into the database. I'm gonna update the code and the log in the main post